# Is it possible to set background text for textfields within java code?

Tags: java, css, javafx, transparent

Possible to set as background text in EditText Field?

```
    TextField field = new TextField("(*.xml, *.java...)");
    field.setStyle("-fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent;");
```

in java?
I dont know the word for it but i want to have the text as a template or so in the background of the editText, like in Login forms and so, any ideas?

Like in the searchfield up here on this site.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The constructor parameter sets the `text`; the CSS property `-fx-prompt-text-fill` sets the color of the *prompt* text (and you haven't provided any prompt text in this code snippet). Which are you trying to make transparent?

Comment: Ok, what i try is to have the text that i set as (....) in cinstructor here to be in background, transparent of the TextField so the user just can add what text itself want into the textField but example is a clue.

Comment: I don't understand that. You're providing some text (`"(*.xml, *.java...)"`), but you don't want the user to be able to see it. But you *do* want them to be able to see the text they type, presumably? None of that really makes any sense to me. If you want the text to be transparent you would use the css `-fx-text-fill: transparent;`, but I'm not sure that is what you're asking.

Comment: Ok thanks! Let take it again, I want to have a visible text for sure but in the background not text you need to wipeout before adding new text, like in login forms, often stands UserName in background, thats what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you are just asking for prompt text?

```
TextField field = new TextField();
field.setPromptText("(*.xml, *.java...)");
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html):

> TextField supports the notion of showing prompt text to the user when
>   there is no text already in the TextField (either via the user, or set
>   programmatically). This is a useful way of informing the user as to
>   what is expected in the text field, without having to resort to
>   tooltips or on-screen labels.